# Question on surface area and volume of cuboid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, volume, rectangles

I came across a question:

> The surface area of the six faces of a rectangular solid are 4, 4, 8, 8, 18 and 18 square cms. The volume of the solid, in cubic centimetres is *_*_.

I can guess that 4 is $lb$, and 8 is $bh$, and 18 is $lh$. But now if I suppose that $b = 2$, then I get $l = 2$ but it makes $h = 9$ which makes $bh = (2)(9) = 18$ false.

Can anyone show a better working for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean to say the surface areas are 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, and 16? That's what you seem to imply when you assume $lh$ is 16.

Comment: @mtiano That's what the question says: '`surface area` of the six faces of a rectangular solid are 4, 4, 8, 8, 18 and 18'

Comment: I posted an answer below. I assume that $lh=18$, if that is not what you meant you can just change it to 16 in my solution and get the answer.

Comment: Oh Oh! I am sorry for the confusion. Corrected. @mtiano Thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 2):

We have $4 \cdot 8 \cdot 18 = lbbhlh$ or $576=l^2b^2h^2$. Taking square roots gives $lbh=24$.

Answer (score 1):

We have, $(lb)(bh) = b^{2}(lh)$. 
So, $4 * 8 = 18b^{2}$ from where we get $b= \frac {4}{3}$ cms 
Therefore $l=3$ cms and $h=6$ cms.
So, volume = $lbh$ = $3 * \frac {4}{3} * 6$ = $24$ cubic cms.